# Missing databases

Tags: mysql, debian

When I start my mysql server with usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql & (debian 7) and I logged to mysql a show databases query result is this:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| UDA                |
| guikuzi            |
| hotel_guregas      |
| merkaklub          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| phpmyadmin         |
| superlinea         |
| test               |
+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and this is a info:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir";
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                      |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| basedir                   | /usr                       |
| character_sets_dir        | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| datadir                   | /var/lib/mysql/            |
| innodb_data_home_dir      |                            |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir | ./                         |
| lc_messages_dir           | /usr/share/mysql/          |
| plugin_dir                | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/     |
| slave_load_tmpdir         | /tmp                       |
| tmpdir                    | /tmp                       |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

After that if I stopped this mysql server and start via /etc/init.d/mysql start I have this:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql start                                                                                                    3 ↵
[ ok ] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
[root@debian:~]
# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 47
Server version: 5.5.35-0+wheezy1 (Debian)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir";
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                      |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| basedir                   | /usr                       |
| character_sets_dir        | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| datadir                   | /var/lib/mysql/            |
| innodb_data_home_dir      |                            |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir | ./                         |
| lc_messages_dir           | /usr/share/mysql/          |
| plugin_dir                | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/     |
| slave_load_tmpdir         | /tmp                       |
| tmpdir                    | /tmp                       |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
```

What´s is happening? I started the safe mode because I have to reset root password, but it´s not working either. Now I have my server in safe mode and it is working but I think that is not the best way

Any help or clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your post, It's quite obvious that in the first instance you started **MySQL** server without its privilege system turned on (--skip-grant-tables). This option turns off **MySQL**'s internal privilege system, which *gives anyone unrestricted access to all databases*. So when you connected to the database server through your client, you bypassed any privilege checks and you could see all databases.

> --skip-grant-tables This option causes the server to start without using the privilege system at all, which gives anyone with access to
>   the server unrestricted access to all databases.
>   "

See [related MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) for more info.

In the second instance, you started **MySQL** normally, the privilege system was turned on which means that connecting users may perform operations that are permitted to them based on their identity.

> The MySQL privilege system ensures that all users may perform only the
>   operations permitted to them. As a user, when you connect to a MySQL
>   server, your identity is determined by the host from which you connect
>   and the user name you specify. When you issue requests after
>   connecting, the system grants privileges according to your identity
>   and what you want to do.

See more info in the [related MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html).

Also, have a look at the answer to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/266758/how-do-i-see-which-user-i-am-logged-in-as-in-mysql) how to see which user is authenticated to your current **MySQL** session.

More simple, just type a "\s" and  to see basic status information in the **MySQL** client prompt. For e.g.:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 38
Server version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Connection id:          37
Current database:
Current user:           ubuntu@localhost
(...)
```

I hope the above helps. I tried to show you a basic pointer how to go about troubleshooting such a situation!